# How do we know which factories class need to use in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

This is the code I copied from MagePlaza.

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

How we will decide that here we need to use PageFactory and why we pass Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context in the constructor.

Can anyone help me out this please?

Answer (score 0):

`Factories` are used everywhere where you need one or multiple instances of same Class.

If you use class itself to load your specific object instead, it will act like `Singleton`, so it will be same instance on every occurrences of that class object not constructed with Factory.

The `Context` is used to tell Magento in which context you are in. For example if you want to get some request data or use registry to load or save some data, you will need to take `Context` in mind, because data could be different in different places.

Comment: Thank you @dudzio for your response.  I understood the concept of Factory and Context . But still I have one confusion regarding the Factory. Sometimes I see people use $_typeFactory and sometimes use $_objectFactory.  How we decide this which type of factory we need to use?

Comment: Factories are autogenerated most of time, every generated factory is stored inside `generated`, there is no difference in those generated classes.
Could you point me to the class containing both factories you are talking about? `$_typeFactory` have that name because of Class name. For example`\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\TypeFactory` which  is Factory for `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type`, but there is nothing more special in it.

Comment: Thank you @dudzio for detailed explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it meet your expectations :)